# How to manually execute commands in maven with Spring STS

Tags: linux, spring, maven, spring-mvc, terminal

**How to execute maven commands with Spring STS manually?**

I use Spring STS with build-in Maven using Linux. I need to add jar manually.
I found that I need to do it by executing this command

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc14.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

It is possible to do it through windows cmd. However, by using terminal in linux I receive output:

```
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

I don't need install another Maven when Spring STS works with an internal Maven.

**How to redirect terminal to use internal Maven in Spring STS ?**

On the top of my head I think to edit MAVEN_HOME, but I am beginner and I prefer to ask you guys first.

Comment: I think you can do Run As... On the makefile and configure it to suit your needs. That said, nothing wrong with a command line maven.

Comment: Also, why not add the jar as a dependency?

Comment: Aha! I understand it now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install jars in maven repository which is eclipse embedded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323981/how-to-install-jars-in-maven-repository-which-is-eclipse-embedded)

Comment: @flup You won't find this oracle driver as a dependency in maven. You need to add it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your focus:
**I don't need install another Maven when Spring STS works with an internal Maven.**
but, in "STS", maven is not configured to work out of STS (and terminal usage is out of STS usage).
we have to install maven.

those who are here with "mvn" is not recognised like erros,
**follow the following to setup maven to work from terminal.**

maven download link is here

1. [download latest maven from here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

   extract it where ever you want.
   i extracted as below (see the bin,boot,conf,... folders are shown below as in the image):
2. [image]

**as this maven download is extracted from zip file (it is not setup), you will have to add this extracted path to "PATH" variable in windows environment.
follow this to set environment path:**
3. [image]

4. [image]

5. [image]

6. [image]

now "mvn" command must work.

7. **in my case, i use STS**
**and i had to restart STS (spring tool suit) for "mvn" to work in terminal in sts**

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but it seems that if you want to use maven from console you will have to install it on your OS.

Look at this:
[Where is mvn.exe when using embedded maven 3 in eclipse indigo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790990/where-is-mvn-exe-when-using-embedded-maven-3-in-eclipse-indigo)

Answer (score 0):

You can also run custom maven goal from within Spring STS by opening `Run Configurations` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkweJ.png)