# STS 3.6.2 - SQL Server Driver/Maven

Tags: spring, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm trying to include the SQL Server Driver in a Spring MVC project.

I'm using STS 3.6.2 which has a embedded version of Maven

How can I accomplish this? I tried to include the driver via Add External Jar but it didn't work. And I read that since [I'm using an embedded version I can't use the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790990/where-is-mvn-exe-when-using-embedded-maven-3-in-eclipse-indigo)

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to add it to the pom as a dependency? Regardless of the fact if you use an internal or external version of maven.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There's no official Maven repository for the SQLServer driver so I need to do something like this "mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0" and then add it to the pom. My problem is that since it's embedded I can´t figure out how to do that.

Comment: Just install maven (well download and unzip) ...

Comment: I tried that at first but for some reason STS kept telling me that the selected directory wasn't a Maven Home, even when it was a valid one (I think it had something to do with the fact that I first selected an invalid one on purpose, so the message was kinda misleading). With a external Maven installation my problem was solved. Thanks again @M.Deinum for helping me in my Spring related issues (this was like the third time)